# Settext pointer exception on fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Set text pointer exception, I get the error.

```
public class FragmentBirinci extends Fragment {

private ImageView settingbtn;
private Button button;
private TextView textView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_birinci_layout,container,false);

    settingbtn = view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView23);

    textView.setText("Hello World");   //ERROR

    settingbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),SettingsActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Ayarlar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

The error i got;

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.vortex.soruhafizam, PID: 6341
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at com.vortex.soruhafizam.FragmentBirinci.onCreateView(FragmentBirinci.java:32)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6341 SIG: 9

I got try this: ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView23)).setText("Hello World");
and
textView = (Textview) view.findViewById(R.id.textView23);
textView.setText("Hello World");

Comment: `textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView23);` this is where the problem lies. It could be that the `view` is not the right fragment OR the `textView23` ID is incorrect. I would recommend debugging > using evaluate expression to determine which one is returning null result.

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView23"/>

Comment: If you are confident that the id is accurate. The problem must be in the `view` itself. Checkout the fragment ID and highly recommend you to go in debug mode and use evaluate expression to search for the underline error. Try sharing the fragment code too.

Comment: Thank you mate, textview id did not match. That's why I was getting an error. The problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView23);` - this is where the problem lies. It could be that the view is not the right fragment OR the textView23 ID is incorrect (highly likely). 
One way to check this would be to go into debug mode and use evaluate expression to determine which one is returning null result. This can be done by simply executing the piece of code which is producing the NullPointerException and from there you should be able to investigate.